# How to change easing into fading in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using [jQuery Tools scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/easing.html) to create picture slides. Is there a way to customize the animation so instead of `easing` it fades-out/fades-in?

Before I try a new plugin, I want to make sure there isn't an easy way to change the transition. I have integrated the plugin in several sections and prefer to extend it instead of using a new plugin.

The authors provide a custom easing function, but I have no idea how to make it fade:

```
// custom easing called "custom"
$.easing.custom = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158; 
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
}
// use the custom easing
$("div.scrollable").scrollable({easing: 'custom', speed: 700, circular: true});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easing function just defines a shape at which a value goes from A to B, it can't explicitly fade in or out. With this library there are events you can listen to - you could try fading out on the `onBeforeSeek` and then fading back in on the `onSeek` events described [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html).

If your container for the items has id = 'items':

```
$(".scrollable").scrollable({
   onBeforeSeek: function (e,i) {
      $("#items").fadeOut();
   },
   onSeek: function (e,i) {
      $("#items").fadeIn();
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks! That does the job of fading, but it messes up the sequence of the photos. Some photos now flash twice, and the fade-in/fade-out appears a little random. Maybe it's not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should set the `speed: 0` so that it's not animating the movement in any way.

Then I would cache the `.items` wrapper so that the function isn't searching the DOM every time.

I would also use `.fadeTo()` instead of `'fadeIn/Out` because all you really want to do is change the opacity, not the `display:property`. See jQuery docs: [.fadeTo()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

You don't need to pass the event `e` and index `i` arguments either:

```
var $items = $('.scrollable .items');

$(".scrollable").scrollable({
    speed: 0,            
    onBeforeSeek: function() {
        $items.fadeTo(0,0);
    },
    onSeek: function() {
        $items.fadeTo('fast',1);
    }
)};
```